# File ownership of created files

Tags: php, nginx, permissions, webserver, ownership

I have 2 php applications running on my server and the files within these applications are owned by 2 users (user1 and user2)

The ownership of the files look like this user1:www-data and user2:www-data. I assign www-data as group so my php application can easily write to the files when the permission is set to 775.
So I set all file permissions to 755 and 775 (for files that have to be written to).

Everything good so far, the only problem is that when my php application created a file it sets the ownership to www-data www-data which is not what I want. I want php to set the permission to iether user1:www-data or user2:www-data depending on which application it is.

I am using Nginx 1.6.3 and php 5.5.24 with php-fpm.

Comment: This is working as expected. You can try `chown()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php and `chgrp()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php

Comment: Ye I thought about that, the problem though is that a PHP framework does all the writing and I don't want to start messing in its files.

Comment: Then I would advise checking into the documentation o your framework to see if this is something the framework already does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the setgid flag on the directory where the files are being saved.

setgid will cause files saved in that directory to be owned by the same group as the directory itself

```
chmod g+s directoryname
```